# Cannot connect to SQL Server using sqlcmd in Docker image, Gitlab CI

Tags: sql-server, docker, continuous-integration

I try to build a CI pipeline where database changes are also tested, but having issues with SQL Server. I defined the following job for this:

```
variables:
  MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: <YourStrong@Passw0rd> 
  ACCEPT_EULA: Y

build_database:
  stage: build
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
  script:
    - cd './Database/Up'
    - /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "$MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD" -Q "SELECT @@VERSION"
    - for file in *.sql; do echo "sqlcmd -i $file"; /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "$MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD" -i $file; done;
```

My SQL scripts are in the `./Database/Up` folder, but I never get to that point to actually execute them, the job fails at the `SELECT @@VERSION` task.

I always get the following output:

```
$ /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "$MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD" -Q "SELECT @@VERSION"
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong? According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-deployment?view=sql-server-2017#buildnonrootcontainer) I should be able to connect to the server using `/opt/mssql-tools18/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P '<YourPassword>'` where the password is specified as an environment variable (just as I defined it as a variable in gitlab CI).

Comment: The SQL Server service doesn't start instantly - it takes time for it to mount, verify and upgrade (where needed) all of the system database and user database files before it opens a socket to accept incoming connections. Sometimes tens of seconds. If you read the [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) it includes a section, _See this example of using an entrypoint.sh and setup.sql scripts to create a database_, that you should read and follow to create or restore databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I was able to make it work by making the server run in a separate service like this:

```
services:
  - name: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
    alias: mssql

variables:
  MSSQL_HOST: mssql
  MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: <YourStrong@Passw0rd> 
  ACCEPT_EULA: Y

build_database:
  stage: build
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
  script:
    - cd './Database/Up'
    - for file in *.sql; do echo "sqlcmd -i $file"; /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S mssql -U SA -P "$MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD" -i $file; done;
```

Probably my mistake was that I wanted to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1, but couldn't figure out what the correct hostname is.